# OptionsMenu showing always on top

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I have an activity with a full screen dialog and an optionsmenu, this problem is that menu always appears behind the dialog. Is there a way to make the menu visible even if the dialog is shown?

Comment: I think there is not direct or easy way of doing this. FrameLayouts, bringToFront functions, z-orders of views, DialogFragment might be an answer

Comment: Are you using a dialog or a dialog fragment?

Comment: @ClaireG, i dont have enough reputation to post images, sorry :(